# Can't open Azure VM Port

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, port

I'm trying to open port 8080 on an Azure VM so that I can access SSAS through Power BI from my local computer. I have added an inbound rule to the network security group on azure portal as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal and I've also added an inbound rule on the firewall of the VM itself.

However, when I go to canyouseeme.org it can't see port 8080.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share some exact details on your NSG? What rules did you create and to what did you assign the NSG?

Comment: I'm not sure how "canyouseeme" works, but I wonder if it can't see the port if nothing is listening on that port.  Did you have something running, listening on the port when you tested?  You can also test with Tcping, a downloadable utility that does "ping like" behavior on any TCP port of your choice.  I know that Tcping does require something to be listening on the port.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The solution was to redeploy the VM after opening the ports on the Azure portal.

Comment: It seems is not a good solution. According to your solution, it seems your service is not started. After you redeploy your VM, your service is listening. So, if you meet this issue again, I suggest you could check your service firstly.

Comment: Hi, I see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48149387/reset-azure-vm-pw-for-domain-controller  Do you add some clients in this domain. If yes, maybe you could rest password. If no, you need create a new domain controller. I met same issue, no way solve this.

Comment: This should not be marked as the solution of the question.

Comment: even this does not fix my problem. I tried this [az vm open-port -g rgname -n vmname --port 8060] . It gave success but port was not opened. Also Disabled firewall and added port. After redeploying, it was still the same moreover I was not able to use Bastion anymore

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I suggest you could check as the following steps:

1.Check Azure VM NSG, port 8080 should be open.

[image]

Note: The link you provided is open port on Vnet subnet, You also need open port on VM's nic.

2.Open port on your VM's Windows Firewall.

3.Port 8080 should be listening on your VM. You could use `netstat -ant|findstr 8080` to check it. If it is not listening, maybe you need check your configuration. This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0) maybe helpful.

Note: The port should listen on `0.0.0.0`. If it is listening on `127.0.0.1`, it only could access inside VM.

Comment: "You also need open port on VM's nic" how is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You also have to make sure that the firewall running on the virtual machine itself is disabled, or allows the specific ports you are interested in.

See here:
https://wiki.u-gov.it/confluence/display/SCAIUS/How+to+disable+firewall+inside+a+linux+virtual+machine

Answer (score 0):

1)Go to VM & open desired port in local firewall setting

Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Defender Firewall

click link -Advanced settings->Inbound rules ->New Rules

select Port option and add your desired port

2)Also On azure, In VM networking, whitelist the port

3 ) netstat -ant|findstr

Above steps worked for me.