# Reset Azure VM pw for Domain Controller

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, domaincontroller

We're using an azure vm as a domain controller and for some reason the local administrator's pw has expired. When trying to reset the pw I get the following error message: "VMAccess Extension does not support Domain Controller."

I have tried unsuccessfully running the suggested script from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/881ac109-fd53-48df-8582-74171104002b/error-message-vmaccess-extension-does-not-support-domain-controller?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows).

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: If you can't connect to a Windows virtual machine (VM), you can reset the local administrator password or reset the Remote Desktop service configuration (not supported on Windows Domain Controllers).
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/reset-rdp

Comment: Thanks, but as stated in my question I get an error when trying to reset the pw.

Answer (score 2):

MS now have this covered with PowerShell access for owners/admin.

1. Navigate to the VM in the Azure Portal.
2. On the left menu:

   2a.  enter "run" into the search textbox and press enter, then click on 'Run Command'

   OR

   2b.  navigate to Operations > Run command
3. Click on EnableAdminAccount then click Run. Use the X in the top right to close the window, and wait for the notification when the script finishes. Select EnableAdminAccount again to see progress if necessary.
4. If step 3 succeeds, cick on "RunPowerShellScript".
5. In line numbered 1 enter "net user [Username] [Password]", then click Run. The [username] here is the RDP user to login with local owner/admin rights.
6. Job done. You should now be able to RDC to your server using the local admin [username] as the login name (ie. \username).

Answer (score 1):

For a DC, the reset is not supported using the normal VM Reset Password option. Instead, use a custom script:

1. Open a new notepad window.
2. Write: net user [Username] [Password]

*Without the brackets and replacing the default values with your own.*

3. Save it as script.ps1
4. Navigate to the VM in the Azure Portal
5. On the left menu under Settings > select Extensions > select Add+
6. Select Custom Script Extension option from the list
7. Select Create
8. Upload the script.ps1 file
9. Select Ok

Answer (score 0):

MSFT Support let me know that it's not possible to log into an Azure VM that is a domain controller VM with the user that is created in the Azure portal when configuring the VM. You can only log in using one of the domain users.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Where can I find info about or create a domain user?

Comment: Hi, didn't you create some domain administrators when setting up your domain?

Comment: No we haven't setup any Azure Domain Services. 
When I created the Virtual Machine I created a local admin user. The password for this user cannot be resetted. When trying to reset I get the same message "VMAccess Extension does not support Domain Controller".

Did you setup Azure Domain Services after the Virtual Machine was created or before?

Comment: I set up domain services after the VM was created. Just to be clear, I logged into the VM and created a domain using Windows server etc, not using Azure Domain Services as such. Did you  do something similar at all?

Comment: Ah ok. No I didn't setup any specific domain on the VM when it was created. And now it isn't possible to login or reset the password. 
Think I need to look into another solution to solve this. Maybe moving the disk to a new VM or something.