# reset azure vm with AD installed

Tags: azure, active-directory

Hello all and thank you for reading,

I have an azure account with VM (windows 2012 server)
I have AD installed

I am trying to reset the password, setup new admin account to no avail.

the error I am getting:
VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'enablevmaccess'. Error message: "VMAccess Extension does not support Domain Controller."

power shell dosn't work as well ( I am no expert)

Thank you for reading this hope someone can help.

Comment: Do you have some VM join this VM?

Comment: If not, it is not possible rest domain user password, see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48149387/reset-azure-vm-pw-for-domain-controller

Comment: what do you mean by VM join ?

Comment: Another Azure VM joins to this AD

Comment: Dear friend, I had a star sysadmin do it for me, worked like a charm

Comment: I asked him to share here, I see its a recurring problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Script Extension (if Azure Agent is running) to execute a password reset script. Use below cmd command in script.

`net user <username> Test@123`

Save the script with Reset-user.ps1 and store it on blob storage.

Run below commands to add CSE extension with script to your VM

```
# Login to Azure account
Login-AzureRmAccount

# get VM
$AzureRmVms = Get-AzureRmVM -Name <name> -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupname>

# CSE Execution
Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension -ResourceGroupName $AzureRmVMs.ResourceGroupName -ContainerName script -FileName Reset-user.ps1 -StorageAccountName storagename -StorageAccountKey "storagekey" -Run Reset-user.ps1 -VMName $AzureRmVMs.Name -Name "Anything" -Location $AzureRmVMs.Location
```

Comment: This is the star sysadmin that helped me, Thank you Prashant

Comment: Here is a recent blog post describing how to do the same thing using the Azure Portal: http://www.chrisjohnson.io/2018/02/15/domain-controller-in-azure-vm-with-expired-password/