# az vm open-port icmp, is that possible?

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, port, icmp

Following up on
[Can't open Azure VM Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47928380/cant-open-azure-vm-port)
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal

Is it possible to open icmp port for `ping` using azure cli, like `az vm open-port` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to open icmp port for `ping` using azure cli, like `az vm open-port`?

Azure NSG now supports ICMP protocol and allows ping to a VM as we can see in the below screenshot from the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview).

[image]

But `az vm open-port` command do not have a parameter to pass `ICMP` protocol, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-open-port).

You could use `az network nsg rule create` command to allow ICMP on a VM as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/nsg/rule?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-nsg-rule-create).